# Is it safe to delete a clustered index in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I have a clustered index on a table is it safe to delete, and if I do, does it leave the table ordered the same way it was while indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always safe to delete technically, but whether it makes sense in a design/architecture/performance prespective we can't say.

The data will remain in the order on disk until update/inserts happen, but please don't rely on that at all, ever. Output is only guaranteed whan you use an ORDER BY in the outermost SELECT

Comment: thanks. i am performance testing a copy of a production database.  i want to delete all the indexes in the current database (creating a non-indexed baseline) and re-apply my own index script until i figure out the best performing indexes.

Answer (score 3):

If is safe to delete it (as long as data integrity is concerned and the index is not `UNIQUE`).

When you delete a `CLUSTERED` index, the table becomes heap organized (i. e. the table rows are not a part of a `B-Tree` anymore), and all other indexes are rebuilt to refer to `RID`s instead of the `index value + uniquifier`.

Note that the table is not "ordered" initially. When you issue this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
```

, the rows are not guaranteed to come in the index order unless you use `ORDER BY` clause.